# Are there mythical creatures in the world of Game of Thrones?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

There are quite a lot of creatures from our real world ancient myths, that exist in the world of GoT: giants, dragons etc.

However, are there any creatures that are mythical in both worlds? Creatures mentioned in either book or show which are mythical both in our real world ancient myths and myths of Westeros/Essos?

The only creature that comes to my mind is the Kraken from Scandinavian myths, as I am not sure if it exists in GoT although it is a symbol of Greyjoys.

Comment: Mermaids and ice dragons off the top of my head

Comment: @aegon Not sure if ice dragons are old mythological creatures, I think they are more a D&D invention.

Comment: Oh they exist in the books, they are not altogether a D&D heresy. But _what_ they are is decisively different than what many believe was an ice dragon in GoT.

Comment: @Aegon I meant Dungeon and Dragons, not showrunners of GoT :)

Comment: Oh sorry, I just read the part that you seek beasts that exist in both our myths and Planetosi myths.

Comment: wait, are you saying that dragons aren't real in our world? :(

Answer (score 46, accepted):

- [Centaurs](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Centaurs) , opinions differ. Some think they actually existed in the dawn age. Others contest that they were no more than mounted warriors who were perceived as such by their victims.
- [Merlings](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Merlings) Merlings, both male and female appear in sigils and stories. But there's no evidence that they exist, nobles like Tyrion Lannister think it's more of peasant nonsense.
- [Grumkins](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Grumkins), don't need much introduction. They appear in bedtime stories and are supposed to grant wishes. Basically like Genies in our world.
- [Harpies](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Harpies), mythical monsters who have head and torso of a human female, Wings of a bat, legs of an eagle and tail of a scorpion. They are famous mostly as symbol of the Ghiscari Empire. Slightly different than our harpies who lack the tail and have avian wings rather than a bat's.
- [Sphinx](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Sphinx) because let it never be said that Ghiscari created a mythical half-human creature and Valyria did not. This one is supposed to have a human face, the body of a lion, the wings of a hawk and the tail of a serpent. Quite similar to Sphinx in the Greek myths.
- [Snarks](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Snarks) also feature in Westerosi bedtime stories. They appear in at least [one work of fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snark_(Lewis_Carroll)) in our world. (Credit: [Raj](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/106383/raj) )
- A [Cockatrice](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Cockatrice) graces the banners of House Gargalen, quite similar to Cockatrice in our world. (Credit: [Nolimon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/89839/nolimon))
- [Griffins](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Griffin) grace the banners of House Connington but there is no evidence that they exist in Planetos. Identical to our Griffins.
- [Hellhounds](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Hellhound) appear in both Westerosi myths and our myths.
- [Sea Dragons](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Sea_dragon) are quite similar to [Sea serpents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_serpent) in our myths. (Credit: [Kepotx](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/87517/kepotx))
- [The Deep ones](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Deep_Ones) are similar to some Lovecraftian creatures. (Credit: [Kepotx](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/87517/kepotx))

Comment: Could you explain in your post why you don't list "_Mermaids and ice dragons_"?

Comment: @Cœur `Merlings, both male and female appear in sigils and stories.`, a female merling is a mermaid. Ice Dragons well I couldn't find ice dragons in any of our historical mythos. Of course there's an argument that we should include ice dragons based on GRRM's earlier works since we are adding the Deep ones and snarks because of other works of fiction

Comment: @Aegon you forgot the [Squishers](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Squishers)

Comment: @josh Are there any equivalents to squishers in our myths?

Comment: Also, Old Nan mentions White Walkers riding "giant ice spiders" that do not appear to be real.

Comment: A loooong string of comments here has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94291/discussion-on-answer-by-aegon-are-there-mythical-creatures-in-the-world-of-game). Creatures discussed there include **manticores** and **unicorns** and **Children of the Forest**, so please don't propose adding them without checking the chat first.

Comment: I think you can add krakens to that list. Although people seem more inclined to believe them, I don't think we get any first hand accounts of one.

Comment: @Ethan Not first hand accounts but plenty of other evidence. When Alyn Velaryon set sail to the Iron Islands from Driftmark, it is noted by Maesters that the sea south of Dorne was infested with Krakens. Maesters are scientific men, if they say something exists and lives in these places, I think that's a good case for accepting their existence. We also have recorded appearance of Krakens around Iron Islands when Aegon the Conqueror came ashore. Also, one of the ships that accompanied Elissa Farman on her exploration west was pulled down by a Kraken. Ofc, Varys reports a Kraken attack too

Comment: Yeah, there's definitely a higher chance they are real in the series than most of the other things. On the other hand, we have real world reasonably scientific accounts of krakens as recently as the late 18th and early 19th centuries. The Westeros accounts could likewise be attributed to dangerous seas and such.

Answer (score 1):

Do supernatural forces count?

Depending on your personal religious views, God would be supernatural but (possibly) not real.

At least the God of Light manifests itself through some physical phenomena in GoT, but it is in general supernatural.

There are claims of other Gods in GoT.  The claims of ancient Olympus Gods are known to be mythical in our world.

Answer (score -2):

GRRM has [recently hinted](https://www.newsweek.com/winds-winter-george-rr-martin-unicorn-skagos-davos-seaworth-rickon-stark-1401384) that in *The Winds of Winter* there will be unicorns.  Sort of.

Comment: So not a mythical creature... sort of